# What did this sum become: $\left(\sum_{n=a}^{b} z_n\right)^2 $?

Tags: summation

Can I see something meaningfull about this sum? Where is it equal to?

$$\left(\sum_{n=a}^{b} z_n\right)^2$$

Is it equal to: $\sum_{n=a^2}^{b^2} z_n^2$ or something else, I've no idea how to deal with it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is $z_n$ something specific or can it be general?

Comment: Just general!!!

Comment: no its not equal to that.... however, you could use the binominal formula to 'simplify' this....

Comment: I dont think there is a general result.

Comment: @Börge Can you give me an example?

Comment: scroll down to the anwer of quid.. he used described it more detailed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string $\sum_{n=a}^b z_n$ means that you take the sum of $z_a + z_{a+1}+ \dots + z_b$. When you square that you compute
$$(z_a + z_{a+1}+ \dots + z_b)(z_a + z_{a+1}+ \dots + z_b)$$ 
and this is not at all what you propose. To get a feeling you might want to try it out for say $a=1$ and $b=3$ spelling out everything in detail.

A general formula would be 
$$ \left(\sum_{n=a}^b z_n\right)^2= \sum_{n=a}^b z_n^2  + 2\sum_{a \le n < m \le b} z_nz_m.$$
Observe the special case $(z_1 +z_2)^2 = z_1^2 + z_2^2 +2z_1 z_2$ that you might have seen elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, it gives me a clear inside!

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\sum_{n=a}^b z_n\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{j=a}^b z_j\right)\left(\sum_{k=a}^b z_k\right) = \sum_{j,k=a}^b z_jz_k$$
If you want, you can pull the squares and reduce repetitive terms into the following form:
$$\left(\sum_{n=a}^b z_n\right)^2 = \sum_{n=a}^b z_n^2 + 2\sum_{j=a+1}^b\left[\sum_{k=a}^{j-1} z_jz_k\right]$$
Unfortunately, there aren't many simplifications (in general) beyond this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer